# Create DLL using C++

Tags: c++, dll

I created a project win32 named Win32DLL to generate DLL in C++ as follow:

```
class CWin32DLL
{
...
};
```

then I build successful the source code and the C++ compiler generate Win32DLL.dll. So from now, I can import my DLL to any project C++.

I do not know why in some projects, they created the file DllExport.cpp in the same project Win32DLL and added the code as following in DllExport.cpp:

```
#include "CWin32DLL.h"
CWin32DLL g_win32DLL;
```

What is the main reason of this implementation?

Comment: Who is "they"? And do I understand you right that you question is why some people create and export a global instance of a class in their DLL?

Comment: "they" means the previous programmer. They added the code in DllExport.cpp. So that is the reason why I do not understand why previous programmer implemented like that. Yes, you are right. Thanks your feedback.

Comment: There is one good reason, and that is when this class can conceptually only have a single instance. There is a bad reason, too, and that is that people think that everything in C++ must be in a class and in order to use this in a modular style they instantiate the class once to represent the module. That said, there is a lot of C++ code out there that is badly written by people that don't fully understand the language, don't follow that lead. Please keep on your path of questioning other code and not following blindly!

Comment: The reason of having global class instance inside Dll is to implement kind of singleton, which may be accessed by clients without creating the class instance. Bad idea, because class constructor is called when Dll is loaded, and destructor is called when Dll is unloaded.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich Eckhardt and Alex Farber a lot